# Displaying text returned from php in loop as separate links on html page

Tags: php, jquery, html, hyperlink

Below is my AJAX code. I've written the questions in the comments.

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "dbtryout2_2.php",
data: datastr,
success: function(arrayphp) {
     //here one by one text is being received from php  from within a loop
     //each text item is getting displayed as link here
     //it is OK that text is getting displayed as link
     //BUT the problem is that all the text returned from php are getting displayed as 
     //one link i.e between one "<a></a>"
     //I WANT THAT EACH TEXT SHOULD BE DISPLAYED AS SEPERATE LINKS
     //AS EACH TEXT IS GETTING RETURNED FROM WITHIN SEPARATE ITERATIONS OF PHP LOOP
     var link = $('<a href="#" class="album"><font color="red">' + arrayphp + '</font></a>');
    linkclass = link.attr("class"); 
    $(".searchby .searchlist").append(link);   
}
});
```

What to do?

Comment: Post the relevant php code or clarify the comment in the code - not sure what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Php throws everything at once to the ajax success function... You need to use json_encode on the php array and echo it to pass it as json array.

```
<?php 
$return = array();
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
 //Do your processing of $value here
 $processed_value = $value;
 array_push($return, $processed_value);
}
echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

In the ajax call set the dataType as "json" for it to parse the data passed from php as json array. Loop across the array received by using jquery each.

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "dbtryout2_2.php",
data: datastr,
dataType: "json",
success: function(arrayjson) {
     $.each(function(arrayjson, function(i, processed_value) {
       var link = $('<a href="#" class="album"><font color="red">' + processed_value + '</font></a>');
       linkclass = link.attr("class"); 
       $(".searchby .searchlist").append(link); 
    });  
}
});
```